# How to remove the unnecessary prefix from the Bookmark section?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, thesis

I am writing thesis using my university's thesis class file. I am using the following command in preamble to get PDF bookmarks.

```
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarks]{hyperref}
```

I am getting unnecessary prefix ("to") before all the chapter names in the bookmark as shown below. I am completely clueless. Does anybody has any clue? Thank you.

[image: Please note the unnecessary prefix "to"]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal example of code?

Answer (score 1):

Package `hyperref` already tries to filter out many commands, which have no meaning in bookmarks. Bookmark are simple text strings and the PDF viewers do not understand TeX markup.

In this case I suspect that `to` comes from the TeX primitive `\hbox` which has `to` as keyword to specify the width of a box. `\hbox` is filtered out and if the width is a dimen register, then also the width, but the keyword `to` remains.

The following example uses a trick to remove keywords after `\hbox` and works for the example. But this is not true in general, because it assumes that `\hbox` is called with curly braces every time. Otherwise when `\bgroup` and `\egroup` is used, the code will fail utterly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\hbox#1#{\@firstofone}% remove \hbox and all up to the next open curly brace
}

\begin{document}
\section{\hbox to \parindent{1\hfill} Funny Section}
\end{document}
```

A cleaner solution would be, if the fix is applied to the markup of the class or package, which you are using.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better `\def\hbox#1#{\@firstofone}`?

Comment: @Manual The curly (non-argument) braces around the box contents for `\hbox` are removed by the bookmark code already, but removing them via `\@firstofone` is more efficient. It might make the error situation, if `\hbox` is used without curly braces, more complex, but the error remains not understandable by the normal user anyway. Thererfore, thanks, I have improved the answer.